# Validação no Angular 9

Tags: angular

Tenho um formulário, e em um dos inputs preciso fazer uma validação para que quando tiver apenas espaços em branco não acontecer nada. Exemplo abaixo:

```
 phone: [this.currentUser ? this.currentUser.user.phone : '', Validators.required],
 cpf: [this.currentUser ? this.currentUser.user.cpf : '', Validators.required],
 obs: [''] // Esse é o input a ser validado
```

Alguém pode me da uma sugestão de como fazer isso?

Answer (score -1):

Crie um método e o chame no front-end (input) = "removeEspaco()"

```
 removeEspaco(){
    this.contact.patchValue({
      obs: this.contact.value.obs.replace(/^\s+/g, "")
    })
  }
```

Resolveu o problema.